# When is it worth it to guess on multiple choice test with 2/0/-1 point for correct/no/incorrect answer.

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a multiple choice test where each question has 4 choices but only 1 answer is correct.

For a correct answer you get 2 points, for no answer you get 0 and for an incorrect answer you get -1.

Sometimes you don't know anything but at other times you can exclude 1 or 2 answers that are definitely wrong.

When is it worth it to just guess and when is it better to give no answers? And how to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For four possible choices, the expected value is $2+3(-1)=-1$.
For three possible choices, the expected value is $2+2(-1)=0$.
For two possible choices, the expected value is $2+(-1)=1$.
For one possible choice (good for you, you studied for your test!), the expected value is $2$.

Therefore, it would be best to:

1. leave blank the questions you know nothing about;
2. do nothing *or* guess the questions you can eliminate one wrong answer;
3. guess the questions you can eliminate two wrong answers; and
4. claim your $2$ points for knowing the answer to the question.

Is this the type of answer you were looking for?